# I am not getting email id value for facebook sign in but getting it for google sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am using firebase auth and google sign in package and flutter facebook auth package

I am able to get the email id value when using google sign in but not getting it while using facebook sign in

here is the code

google_sigincontrol.dart

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
GoogleSignInAccount ? _user;
GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;


Future facebookLogin() async {

  final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
  if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {

    final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken!.token);

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

  notifyListeners();
}
Future googleLogin() async {
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  if (googleUser == null) return;
  _user = googleUser;

  final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

screen.dart

```
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
        ),
      SizedBox(height: 8),
      Text('Name: '+ user.displayName!,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 16),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8),
      Text('Email: '+ user.email!,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 16),
      ),
```

Can anyone provide a fix for this